# Is $B_1(0) \setminus \{a_n\}$ open or not given $a_n \rightarrow a \in B_1(0)$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a complex sequence in the open unit ball such that the sequence converges to some $a \in B_1(0)$, is $B_1(0) \setminus \{a_n\}$ open or not?

I wanna say it is NOT open. Take the sequence $\frac{1}{n+1}$ (I used $n+1$ as $\frac{1}{1}=1 \not\in B_1(0)$) which converges to $0 \in B_1(0)$ but $B_1(0) \setminus \{\frac{1}{n+1}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is NOT open in the standard topology.  Thanks in advance for any hints or help or edits. Btw sorry if this is a duplicate, I could not find a version of it.

Comment: If all the terms of the sequence are different from the limit $a$, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: @Surb I think that $B(0) - \{a_n\}$ means $B(0)$ minus every point of sequence, not for any $n$ fixed. In your example, $0\in (-1,1) - \{a_n\}$ but every open set containing 0 has some (infinites!) element of the sequence and is therefore not included in $(-1,1) - \{a_n\}$

Comment: it is not open if and only if $\{a_n: \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is infinite.

Comment: in the case that the sequence takes on infinitely many values, $B_r(a)$ is not wholly contained in $B_1(0)\setminus\{a_n\}$ for any $r>0$ since for each positive $r$, there are infinitely many $a_n$ in $B_r(a)$.

Comment: @CSquared so I was correct? since the sequence is infinite, the statement is false as $B_1(0) \setminus \{a_n\}$ is not open. for $a_n:=\frac{1}{n+1}$, correct?

Comment: you were partially correct. in the case that the sequence only takes on finitely many terms, then the set $B_r(a)$ is a subset of $B_1(0)\setminus\{a_n\}$ for some $r>0$, hence $B_1(0)\setminus\{a_n\}$ is open. there are two cases which doesn't allow for the question to have a binary yes or no answer

Comment: @CSquared so if my sequence has infinitely many points it is NOT open?

Comment: @MyMathYourMath if the sequence has infinitely many distinct terms, then $B_1(0)$ is not open, as explained above.